# How to select the nearest value for two columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I need to retrieve the row with the nearest value using two columns.
the example below work for one column, but how about two columns?

```
order by abs(Column_X - myvalue_X) limit 1
```

I need to something like this:

```
order by abs(Column_X - myvalue_X),abs(Column_Y - myvalue_Y) limit 1 //wrong row
```

I´m using postgres with postgis

Comment: We need more details since your query technically should run just fine. Is it not calculating the correct row? Should it be the sum of the differences that you're ordering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure with postgre syntax and what you really up to, but if you want to compare with 2 field,  how about using [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)

Some thing like

```
order by ((Column_X - myvalue_X)*(Column_X - myvalue_X) + (Column_Y - myvalue_Y)*(Column_Y - myvalue_Y)) limit 1
```

Comment: This is almost the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), except for ordering `sqrt()` isn't necessary (unless you actually need the distance). You can remove the repetition in the SQL by squaring each difference using `^2`.

Comment: Thanks. I am using this trick on a big database (800MB+) in sqlite. It performed very bad (7+sec for 1 query). To speed things up you can make your set smaller like this: `WHERE Column_X > myvalue_X - somenumber AND Column_X < myvalue_X + somenumber AND Column_Y > myvalue_Y - somenumber AND Column_Y < myvalue_Y + somenumber` where somenumber is the biggest distance between 2 rows. This will make the set to order smaller and thus faster (in my case to ~0,04 sec).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean.  Do you want he row where the *sum* of the two columns is closest to the sum of the same two columns in the original row?  or the *product*? *alphabetically*?

Assume it's the sum.   Use a subquery

```
Select * From Table t1
  join table t2
     on t1.colA + t1.colB = 
         (Select Max(colA + colB)
          From Table
          Where colA + colB < t1.colA + t1.colB)
```

If you man the product, then

```
Select * From Table t1
  join table t2
     on t1.colA * t1.colB = 
         (Select Max(colA * colB)
          From Table
          Where colA * colB < t1.colA * t1.colB)
```